# Finding Missing Constraint

Tags: xcode, autolayout, constraints, interface-builder

When I build my app Xcode gives me five warnings relating to missing constraints.  But clicking on them in the Navigation Panel only takes me to a ViewController in the Storyboard and doesn't highlight which view has the problem.

[image]

In addition, as shown above, the Storyboard doesn't contain any yellow triangles at all, so I'm at a loss as to how to find which view is missing the constraints.

The errors don't appear when I run the app, so how to I try to trap these errors in the build?

(Xcode 14.2)

Comment: Does it also give this warning during the build, or only JIT compilation? If it doesn't show them during compilation from clean, then probably some xcode screw up

Comment: @rapiddevice - errors appear in Navigation Panel every time I build or run the app.  Clicking on error shows a VC in Storyboard that contains a ```UITableView``` and associated cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode and Storyboards have lots of bugs...

One that you're encountering is the failure to show error/warning indicators.

This is how it *should* look:

[image]

Clicking that indicator will show you the specific warnings - and hovering over one shows you the view in question:

[image]

However, those indictors and descriptions are sometimes missing. Seems to happen most often when you have multiple view controllers in a single Storyboard.

You *could* copy each controller to a new Storyboard to see if the information shows up - but, based on my experience, it's hit-or-miss.

In your specific case, warnings such as:

> Leading constraint is missing, which may cause overlapping with other views.

can be safely ignored... provided ***you*** know and understand the layout you've designed.

Comment: thanks for the reassurance! Great pity that error warnings seems to be worse in latest version of Xcode

Comment: @GBasher - many people like using Storyboard for UI design... but it has **many, many** issues. Take this specific case for example: *"... may cause overlapping ..."*. Well, as the designer/developer, I **know** there won't be another view to overlap. In addition, suppose I give the label a Width constraint to prevent it from expanding and overlapping other views? Now SB tells me: *"Fixed width constraints may cause clipping."* ?!?!? So, I give it a large Trailing constraint - which will ***do the same thing*** as giving it a Width constraint, and -- no more warning?

Comment: @GBasher - personally, I will sometimes use Storyboard to *prototype* my UI layout, but then I will write the entire thing in code. For me, it makes it easier to modify (if/when needed), and because I'm including plenty of comments while writing the constraints I know ***exactly*** what what is and is not needed.